# accessing sub directory in python

Tags: python, file, text, directory

I'm trying to access a folder that is in the current directory in which I am writing my code.  the folder I am currently in is cs113

I've tried to do

```
file2 = open("/cs113/studentstoires/Zorine.txt", "r)"
```

Would someone please tell me whey this doesn't work I've also tried to write the directory name like this:

```
open("/studentstories/Zorine.txt", "r")
```

Do I need to import sys and use sys.listdir or os.path? If so can you please give a quick little example how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider using `os.path.join`. Also, please include the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the current directory, and **it's the directory where you execute the script from**, you should write the path without the `/` up front like so:

```
file2 = open("studentstories/Zorine.txt", "r")
```

Comment: Hi @DirtyDaver, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @DirtyDaver And glad I could help :-)

Comment: I think this answer deserves more votes. Not easy to find this info.